# jmeter maven - running jmx file gives Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver

Tags: maven, jmeter

Setup a maven project for jmeter. 
Added the jmx file in src/test/java.

When trying to run the jmx file, getting the following error in the console.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.companyname.automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>apiautomation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Try using the latest plugin. The version is 1.10.1

Answer (score 1):

There are few inconsistencies in your setup:

1. JMX file(s) should live under src/test/**jmeter** folder
2. You need to add the following section after `<version>1.4.1</version>` line:

   ```
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>jmeter-tests</id>
           <phase>verify</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>jmeter</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
   </executions>
   ```
3. Use `mvn clean verify` to run your test.

References:

- [Basic Configuration](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Basic-Configuration) chapter of JMeter Maven Plugin documentation
- USE APACHE MAVEN section of [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Yes, this is what you should be doing according to documentation. Move your jmx file(s) there

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. My tests are running fine after I have changed the pom and created necessary folder structure.